# Bulk POST request without enumerating objects

Tags: api, rest, http, api-design

I'm trying to let my API clients make a POST request that bulk modifies objects that the client doesn't have their IDs.

I'm thinking of implementing this design but I don't feel good about it, are there any better solutions than this?

POST `url/objects/modify?name=foo`

This request will modify all objects with the name `foo`

Answer (score 1):

This can be a tricky thing to do with an API because it doesn't age very well.

By that I mean that over time, you might introduce more criteria for the data stored on resources (e.g., you can only set this field to "archived" if the `create_time` field is older than 6 months). When that happens, your bulk updates will start to only work on some resources and now you have to communicate that back to the person calling the API.

For example, for any failures you need to explain that the update worked for some resources (and list them out) but failed on others (and list them out) and the reason why for each failure (and remember you might have different failure conditions for different resources).

If you're set on going down this path, the closest thing I can think of is the "criteria-based delete" method shown here: https://google.aip.dev/165.